# Setting dataframe cell values with mixed numerical and label-based selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tl;dr - what's the best practice to set cell values when accessing rows by numerical index (as in iloc, iat) and columns by label?

If I use `.iloc`, I get the `"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"` error.

If I use `.iat`, I can't select the cell from the row using the column name, only index.

I prefer to use the column names to maintain readability, and keep the code compatible going forward if the structure of my dataset changes the order of the columns.

I am using `iat`/`iloc` rather than `at`/`loc` because the indexes column of the df contains duplicate values inherited from the datasets that were merged to create it.

I have a dataframe with a text column that I am parsing into new columns.
For example:

|  | A | Text | Team | Room | Person |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'a' | '1 , red , 123 , anna' |  |  |  |
| 2 | 'b' | '1 , blue, 204, ben' |  |  |  |
| 2 | 'c' | '0, red, 23, carl' |  |  |  |
| 3 | 'd' | '0, blue, 123, anna' |  |  |  |

I parse the "Text" column, and I want to enter its contents into the team, room and person columns.

I can't use `.iat` because then I get both lines indexed as `2`  (those with A='b', A='c') in my mock dataset.
I can do the following and get the "setting on a copy" error mentioned above:

```
def parser(df):
    newdf = df
    for i in range(len(df)):
        txt = df.iloc[i]['Text']
        if type(txt) == str: # this skips 'NaN' message rows
            splits = txt.split(', ')
            dic = {'team': splits[1], code: splits[2], 'person': splits[3]}
            newdf.iloc[i]["Team"] = dic["team"]
            newdf.iloc[i]["Room"] = dic["room"]
            newdf.iloc[i]["Person"] = dic["person"]

    return newdf
```

If I use `.iat[i,'Team']` for example, I get the error:
`ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers`

So... is there any solution to this or should I keep ignoring the "setting on copy" warning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy method to create a new DataFrame.

```
def parser(df):
    newdf = df.copy()  # Create a copy of the DataFrame
    for i in range(len(df)):
        txt = df.iloc[i]['Text']
        if type(txt) == str:  # This skips 'NaN' message rows
            splits = txt.split(', ')
            dic = {'team': splits[1], 'room': splits[2], 'person': splits[3]}
            newdf.at[i, "Team"] = dic["team"]
            newdf.at[i, "Room"] = dic["room"]
            newdf.at[i, "Person"] = dic["person"]
    return newdf
```

Comment: Thank you! This did prevent the error.
I'm trying to understand - why is it different? I had assumed `newdf = df` was already creating a copy, in the sense that it's a new dataframe with the same content.

Comment: This solution requires that the index be numerical (1,2,3). I noticed this when I indexed my dataframe by timestamp and this solution stopped working. 
Still a good solution, but it depends on an unrelated condition: you can select numerically with "at" similarly to "iat" if the index is numerical.

Answer (score 1):

Instead loop solution use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `\s*` regex for optionally space before and after `,`, then select 2., 3. and 4. columns by position in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df[['Team','Room','Person']] = df['Text'].str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True).iloc[:, 1:4]
print (df)
     A                  Text  Team  Room Person
0  'a'  1 , red , 123 , anna   red   123   anna
1  'b'    1 , blue, 204, ben  blue   204    ben
2  'c'      0, red, 23, carl   red    23   carl
3  'd'    0, blue, 123, anna  blue   123   anna
```